# How can you show values of UISlider below it on screen like shown in the picture?

Tags: ios, uislider

[image]

I am new to ios development.I have to design this screen.I have used image to show numbers below slider but it does not look good on large screen.Please tell me the other ways to do it.And please tell me that how can i set coordinates if i want to draw these numbers as i am using autolayout.
Thanks

Comment: i will suggest you to use iOS's new Stackview or horizontal Collection view below the slider and adjust your slider value code ...

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a bit more ..how can i use horizontal collection view here?

Comment: @KKb Insteaded of displaying each number individually you can show only single number (Actual value of slider) at the middle of the screen.

Comment: @KKb you only need help for make 0 to 100? right? how to show 0-100 right?

Comment: @AshokLondhe ..I need to show all numbers

Comment: @VvkAghera ..Yes, 0-100 or 0-50

Comment: @VvkAghera.. and the numbers should match the value os slider also as we slide it.

Comment: @KKb the lable design of 0-100 is done.

Comment: @VvkAghera .. i need to show numbers from 0-100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically, take a look at *Vvk Aghera*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579603/3947107). If you want to do it 'visually' with interface builder, the easiest way to accomplish that is by using [stack views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html).

## 1. Set up your view

In Interface Builder you add a slider element and a label per number (so 11 in total).

Put the labels in a horizontal stack view, and set the distribution to '*fill equally*' in the attributes inspector:

[image: attributes inspector]

You can also easily configure the text color and center the alignment of the labels by selecting all of them and opening the attributes inspector:

[image: attributes inspector of multiple labels]

Put the horizontal stack view and the slider in a vertical stack view, giving you something like this:

[image: Slider with labels]

This is what your view hierarchy should look like:

- Stack View (vertical)

  - Slider
  - Stack View (horizontal)

    - label
    - label
    - ...

Screenshot:

[image: View hierarchy]

## 2. Configure slider

Then you can [configure the slider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html) using the attributes inspector. There you can for instance set the maximum value to 100:

[image: Slider attributes]

If you need help with wiring up the slider to your controller and accessing its value, take a look at these tutorials:

- *iOS Creator*'s [UISLider tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/uislider-tutorial-ios8-swift)
- *Ray Wenderlich*'s [A Simple iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115279/swift-2-tutorial-part-2-a-simple-ios-app)

Don't forget the [UISlider class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..let try this!

Comment: I updated my answer with some easy to follow tutorials on how to access the value of the slider in your controller.

Comment: .thanks to you for making this task really easy for me.Stack view is really useful for developers!!

Answer (score 1):

with using UICollectionView use your ViewController like....
first make one UICollectionView Cell and we are using Prototype Cell.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UICollectionView *clnView;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.clnView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Slider Action

-(IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    float value = slider.value;
    NSLog(@"value::::%f",value);
}

#pragma mark - Collection View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 11;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CellNumber *aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellNumber" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    aCell.lblNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row*10];
    return aCell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return CGSizeMake(self.clnView.frame.size.width/15, self.clnView.frame.size.height);
}
```

**CellNumber** is your Custome CollectionViewcell. see below...

**CellNumber.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CellNumber : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *lblNo;

@end
```

Nothing to do in .m file of cell. 
Than go to story board and make prototype cell and give all Outlets.
 On **Storyboard**:

1) add collection view horizontal

2) add cell identifier and class.

3) add UILable in cell and set outlet

4) add slider and set Outlet than set ValuChange Action.

See all images Below....
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help..let me try this!

Comment: @KKb are you stucked?